# SQL query - group by string prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling with a grouping query. 
I have simple table named CarParts where some car elements stored in it. 
Some of those elements are available (with Type prefix "05") and some are blocked (Type prefix "01").

I want to write select query that would group my table CarParts by SerialNr and Type as shown below on the right side.

[image]

Comment: Post your script you are trying with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want conditional aggregation?

```
select serialnr, name,
       sum(case when type like '%-05' then amount else 0 end) as [05-available],
       sum(case when type like '%-01' then amount else 0 end) as [01-blocked]
from carparts
group by serialnr, name;
```

Comment: Yes that's it! :D Thank you Gordon for your help - I remember that I used your solution and it worked pretty well for me. I just forgot then to say thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT to get your desired result as below-

```
SELECT SerialNr,
ISNULL([05-Available],0) [05-Available],
ISNULL([01-Available],0) [01-Available],
Name 
FROM
(
SELECT SerialNr,Amount,Name,RIGHT( Type,2) +'-Available' AS P_Column
FROM CarParts
) AS P
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR P_Column IN ([01-Available],[05-Available])

) AS PVT
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use case when

```
select SerialNr,Name,
   sum(case when right([Type],2)='01' then amount else 0 end) as blocked_01
   sum(case when right([Type],2)='05' then amount else 0 end)  as availabe_05
   from tbale_name group by SerialNr,Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select SerialNr, 
       sum(case when Type  like '%-05' then Amount  else 0 end) as '05-available',
       sum(case when Type like '%-01' then Amount else 0 end) as '01-blocked',
       Name
from carparts
group by SerialNr, Name
```